# Need help to make mongo $lookup query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid

This is my table structure

- Group -> _id,name,description,type
- GroupMembers -> _id, group(FK),status,Isinvited, user_id(Fk)
- User -> _id,name,email,role

Need :- I want to get groups with its active members (status = true) aslo need the name of users from User collections

Current Code :-

```
  Group.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: "groupmembers",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "group",
           as: "membersList"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup : {
           from: "users",
           localField: "membersList.user",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "userss"
        }
    },
    {
      $match:{"_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5abe70eb7ede1b695e9342d6")} 
    },
    {
      $project:{"_id":1,"name":"$name","member":{"membersList":"$membersList","userss":"$userss"}}
    }

  ])
```

Getting the response but not in well manners go like ->

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5abe70eb7ede1b695e9342d6",
        "name": "Welcome To Hobnobbin",
        "member": {
            "membersList":["Got memebrsLiset from GroupMembers"],
            "userss": ["Got users from groupMembers FK "]
        }
    }
]
```

How can I get it like

```
    [
    {
        "_id": "5abe70eb7ede1b695e9342d6",
        "name": "Welcome To Hobnobbin",
        "member": {
            "membersList":["Got memebrsLiset from GroupMembers",user: "Userobject here"],

        }
    }
]
```

Collections : ->

```
    var GroupSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,  
    required: 'Please fill Group name',
    trim: true
  },
  photo:{
      type:String     
  },
  type: {
      type: [{
         type: String,
         enum: ['child', 'adult']
      }],     
      required: 'Please select at least one type'
  },
  description:{
      type:String,
      default:''
  },
  pinnedTweet:{
      type:String,
      default:''
  },
  /*members: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],*/
  jointype: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['openToJoin', 'openToRequest', 'inviteOnly'],
    default: 'openToJoin',
    required: 'Please select at least one behavious of group'
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  createByHobnob: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isWelcomeGroup: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  allowPrivateChat: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

    var GroupMemberSchema = new Schema({
      user : {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      group : {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Group'
      },
      role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['member', 'ban', 'moderator', 'admin'],
        default: 'member',
        required: 'Please select at least one role'
      },
      is_active: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
      },
      is_invited: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
      },
      created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
      allowChat: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      }
    });

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    }
});
```

Comment: NO any answer for this or its impossible result that I expect !!

Comment: Your expected result is not a valid object, as `['...', user: '...']` won't work. Could you fix it and maybe elaborate a bit more on it?

Comment: can you please post your sample collections and output

Comment: Hi @AnthonyWinzlet I had already provide that

Comment: You have posted your output... I need your all the collection samples i.e. `group`, `groupmembers` and `users`

Comment: Yes, let me Edit the Question and add collection their

Comment: Hii @AnthonyWinzlet For you suggestion I have added my full collection in questions

Comment: you have posted your schema... I want your sample collection... sample collection is a JSON object which you do store in your database... So kindly copying it from robomongo or mongo shell and paste them here